# One-piece short distillation glassware - worth it?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Does anyone have any experience using one-piece short distillation setups similar to this: https://www.hornik.eu.com/en/3-985_distillation-bridges/8216-distilling-link-for-short-path-distillation-duran-cones-ns1423-socket-ns1423.html?

I've been struggling with a tricky distillation recently and was wondering whether something like the above would help. I wanted to hopefully get some opinions before shelling out.

Cheers

Comment: Why use such a small device ?

Comment: Define "tricky."

Comment: If tricky means you must collect only few drops than that is of immense help.

Comment: @Maurice come on, why asking?

Comment: @Alchimista I'm trying to distill off 1-2 mL of my product, which has vapours coming off at ~65C. I'm trying to heat the crude to no more than 90C to prevent possible product breakdown. Currently I'm having trouble coaxing the vapours up and into the condenser - I'm having to use plenty of tin foil to try and trap the heat in the glassware between the crude RBF and the condenser.

Comment: @Zhe See my response to Alchimista

Comment: @Technocratic yes you need a micro apparatus — milliapparatus in this case ;-) something like in the pic. Not too micro because they are expensive. Look around if you are at an institution. There should be something even to borrow from a group.

Comment: Maybe try Kugelrohr.

Comment: The complete all in one kits can be a pig to clean, much more so if a flask is incorporated. This doesn't look too bad. Are you using cotton wool or glass wool underneath the foil? I wouldn't spend out on tin foil, aluminium is cheaper 

Comment: @Beerhunter I'm not using cotton/glass wool underneath the foil - would you recommend? And yes I meant to say aluminium! I've bought a one-piece short distiller similar to the one in the picture so fingers crossed it'll be worth it.

Comment: When the insulation really matters, and it can do on these smaller kits, I would use one of those options, then foil and use cable ties/wire to secure a snug fit